# Google spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate with Google Cloud Functions and NodeJS and 'googleapis' throws an error

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-sheets-api

I am trying to make a batchUpdate to google sheets api via nodejs (v18.14.0). The documentation is somehow inconsistent. I tried different variations based on the docs

- [google developers: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate) stating to use `resource`
- [google API: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/googleapis/latest/sheets/classes/Resource$Spreadsheets$Values.html#batchUpdate) stating to use `requestBody`
  or here
- [github example: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/main/samples/sheets/insert-column.js) shows `resource:` with a nested `requests` object

This is my code:

```
my_data = [{
            majorDimension: 'ROW',
            range:'D21',
            values:[[2]]
        }];


res = await this._service.spreadsheets.values.batchUpate({
   spreadsheetId: 'my_spreadsheetId',        
   requestBody: {     // also tried resource instead of requestBody
      valueInputOption: 'RAW',
      data: my_data
   }
});
```

When invoking the code above and all variations I am getting a TypeError with message `'this._service.spreadsheets.values.batchUpate is not a function'`.

Note: I am using `spreadsheets.values.update` and `spreadsheets.values.append` without any issues.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, I think that `batchUpate` should be `batchUpdate`.
- `majorDimension: 'ROW',` should be `majorDimension: 'ROWS',`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
my_data = [
  {
    majorDimension: "ROWS",
    range: "D21",
    values: [[2]],
  },
];
res = await sheets.spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate({
  spreadsheetId: 'my_spreadsheetId',
  requestBody: {
    valueInputOption: "RAW",
    data: my_data,
  },
});
```

- In this case, the value is put into "D21" of the 1st sheet. If you want to put the value to the specific sheet, please use the A1Notation including sheet name like `'Sheet2'!D21`.

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the response is the same as before: "TypeError: this._service.spreadsheets.values.batchUpate is not a function". I think there is something wrong with the google sheets object. That's how it is created: const client = new JWT({ <jwt token here>}); this._service = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', auth: client });

Comment: @stot Thank you for replying. About `but the response is the same as before: "TypeError: this._service.spreadsheets.values.batchUpate is not a function".`, from your error message, it seems that you don't correctly reflect my proposed answer. In your error message, `this._service.spreadsheets.values.batchUpate` occurs an error. But, unfortunately, the spell of `batchUpate` is not correct. It's `batchUpdate`. Please confirm this again.

Comment: @stot I think that if your client of `this._service` is a valid client, by this modification, your script works. And, I confirmed that when I tested my proposed modified script, no error occurs.

Comment: Yes, thanks it was the wrong spelling...